# Magento 2: Reset password link returns 404 page

Tags: password, magento-2.2.5

I seem to have a problem with the reset-password-page in Magento 2.2.5.
On my dev server with email configured, I successfully receive the reset-password-link via mail. Checking the database reveals that the rp_token is updated once I request a new password reset. However, visiting the reset link gives me a magento-404-page. ("Whoops, our bad...").

I also tried to create a fresh local install of Magento 2.2.5. Except I didn't set up email and just used the URL pattern to manually create the reset link with the corresponding data from the database (after I went through the forgot-password-form, so the token gets updated). Still the same 404 error.

It doesn't seem to be a problem with Magento itself since I also tried a fresh install of Magento 2.1.7 with the same

## Edit:

I configured the email service via mageplaza/module-smtp on my fresh Magento 2.1.7 install and the reset-password link works now. So the problem seems to lie there. The original install on my dev server is actually a migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2, I haven't touched the email settings since they were working fine for everything else. I'll try to mess around with the settings and keep this post updated, in case anyone runs into a similar problem.

disclaimer: this is my first Magento project

## Edit 2:

Configuring mageplaza/module-smtp on my dev server didn't seem to help. All emails are being sent correctly, but the reset-password-link is still returning a 404 error.

## Last Edit:

Looks like reverting the email templates back to the corresponding defaults at "Stores>Configuration>Customers>Customer_Configuration>Password_Options" in combination with a configured mageplaza smtp-module has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, there was an extra word "admin" appearing in the reset URL.

So in the password reset email received a link that caused 404 like:

https://mysite.com/admin/specialmagurl/...

The URL worked after I changed it to:

https://mysite.com/specialmagurl/...

Now I'm trying to figure out where the "admin" can be removed.